# AWS buckets location

Tags: .htaccess

Hi and thanks in advance for your answers!
Yesterday I set up an AWS S3 bucket. Today I can not find it. If I try to create another one with the same name, it tells me it already exists. What have I done wrong?
Please keep it simple - no coding!
Kelvin

I have followed AWS guides but it just does not show. For reference, it's a back-up of a web site, the bucket name is u3aoliva and the region (I believe) is Europe - London.

Answer (score 0):

Buckets names are global.
The S3 console is not tied to a given region, when you connect to the account you used to create the bucket you will find it.
If you connect to another account you won't find it.

Check which account you used to create the bucket and which account you are using looking for it.